# How to join mysql query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have these tables

`AssigenmentList` --linksto ---`School`,`AgeGroup`

`Users` will have `birthday` attached to it

1. AgeGroup in turn linked to many ages like  AgeGroup 3-4 is linked to `one to many` with 3,4 in numerical format

Now i want all the Assignment list which are linked to particular SCHOOL belong to same age as the age of Child

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.* from 
    A a inner join B b on a.idB = b.id
        inner join C c on b.idC = c.id
```

You use `inner join` if `a.idB` must have match to add the row to the resultset. Left outer join if the mere presence of `a.idB` (left side) is enough to project the row.

The trick is to navigate from the starting table to the last joining the columns that ties them.